# Python/Matlab comm over TCP

Tags: python, matlab, sockets, tcp

**Edit**
Worked around this problem by switching to UDP. See that updated code snippets after the break.

I'm having trouble with my *threaded tcp* server in python. The goal is to establish a communication link between *Matlab* and a *Python* server to allow for querying a database. This example only works properly once, then I have to restart Matlab to get the message echoed back again.

The Python side:

```
import SocketServer
from threading import Thread

class service(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = 'dummy'
        print "Client connected with ", self.client_address
        while len(self.data):
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            print self.data
            self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

        print "Client exited"
        self.request.close()


class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass

t = ThreadedTCPServer(('',1522), service)
t.serve_forever()
```

And the Matlab Code:

```
t = ThreadedTCPServer(('',1522), service)
t.serve_forever()

t = tcpip('localhost', 1522);
fopen(t);

% write a message
fwrite(t, 'This is a test message.');

% read the echo
bytes = fread(t, [1, t.BytesAvailable]);
char(bytes)

% close the connection
fclose(t);
```

So, while i'm expecting the data to get echoed back, this only occurs on the first run, i.e. right after I've started Matlab. If I run it again, I get the message on the python side, but it is not echoed again. Ideas?

---

The Updated Python Code:

```
 x = np.array([[55, 1000, 45], [20, 3, 10]])

 class UDP_Interrupt(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def setup(self):
        pass

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        print data
        socket = self.request[1]
        print "{}{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0], self.client_address)
        print data
        print x
        socket.sendto(x.tostring('C'), self.client_address)
        #scipy.io.savemat('/Users/empire/Documents/MATLAB/hybridQuadSim/quaternionController/models/mapData.mat', mdict={'mapData': x})

    def finish(self):
        pass

class ThreadedUDPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.UDPServer):

    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    map_server = ThreadedUDPServer((HOST, PORT), UDP_Interrupt)

    # terminate with Ctrl-C
    try:
        server_thread = Thread(target=map_server.serve_forever)
        server_thread.daemon = False
        server_thread.start()
        print "Server loop running in thread:", server_thread.name

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```

And for Matlab:

```
% connect to the server
t = udp('localhost', 2002);
fopen(t);

% write a message
fwrite(t, 'This is a test message.');

% read the echo
bytes = fread(t, [t.BytesAvailable, 1], 'char');
temp = reshape(bytes, [8 6]);
z = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
for col = 1:6
        bytepack=uint64(0);
        for row = 1:8
                temp(9-row, col)
                bytepack = bitshift(temp(9 - row, col),8*(8-row));
                z(col) = bitor(bytepack,z(col));
                temp(row, col);
        end;
end;

% close the connection
fclose(t);
```

This setup seems to work well enough, but would appreciate any feedback or corrections offered. I would like a more robust solution to the problem of reconstructing the numpy array into a matrix in Matlab.